# What benefit does Graphql provide over JBuilder in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, jbuilder

I've been hearing a lot of developers raving about Graphql. After implementing in Ruby on Rails, I've begun to realize that it essentially does the same thing as JBuilder, which is built-in to Rails 5.

From a Rails perspective, what benefit does Graphql provide over JBuilder? Are they essentially used for the same thing? Is there something I'm missing in regards to Graphql?

Comment: TBH I fail to see where did you seen a similarity between those two. Maybe explicitly write down in your question, what criteria are you taking into account in your comparison?

Comment: @Horusiath Well I did a Graphql tutorial and it seemed to me that it was only used for customizing JSON responses. What else is it used for?

Comment: @dcporter7: if that was a "hello world" tutorial, then it's possible. You need deeper info. I personally found this course to be useful: [Building Scalable APIs with GraphQL](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/graphql-scalable-apis/table-of-contents).

Comment: Even comparing to jbuilder, it (jbuilder) looks primitive in comparison. Can client control the fieldsets there and instruct the server which relations to traverse? Didn't think so. Get a better tutorial :)

Answer (score 2):

One of the advantages of GraphQL is the fact, that it's a formally specified standard with its own query language.

It's safely-typed standard with its own specification. This means, you can interop with servers written in different tech stacks using the same query language and type system.

Since it's standardized, a few frontend js libs ([Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/) and [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/client/)) have taken advantage of that, making it very easy to cache and define tailored, client-scoped queries and mutations.

It exposes its own structure as so called [Introspection API](http://graphql.org/learn/introspection/). This means that, you can document your API and query it using GraphQL itself - its self-descriptive. This gives a space for tooling support - example of such is [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql), which allows to explore GraphQL schemas with ease. When using GraphQL, this feature is basically granted for free. You can see it in action i.e. in [Github API Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/), which also uses Ruby implementation of GraphQL AFAIK.

While most people think about it in terms of request/response, it also exposes publish/subscribe capabilities as GraphQL subscriptions via web sockets. Also within a standard.